# Stunnel - SMTP Authentication failed

Tags: stunnel

Hi ServerFault community,

I have posted this to the stunnel-users mailing list on 30 April 2018 and again on 16 May 2018 at https://www.stunnel.org/pipermail/stunnel-users/2018-April/006000.html, unfortunately no one there seems to know the answer, so now I am trying my luck with the experts here.

The following is a verbatim quote from the mail to the mailing list.

> Hi List,
>
> I have just joined the stunnel community.
>
> I am in the process of migrating our mailserver's public facing ports
>   to stunnel for PCI compliance reasons.
>
> So far i have managed to get working:
>
> - imap (143/tcp) with starttls
> - imaps (993/tcp)
> - pop3 (110/tcp) with starttls
> - pop3s (995/tcp)
>
> My trouble is with smtp(25/tcp,587/tcp) with starttls.
>
> I have now tried a couple different mail clients and everyone of them
>   tells me that the server does not support the authentication
>   protocols.
>
> I have installed stunnel 5.44. Tee relevant parts in my config:
>
> ```
> [mail2-imap]
> protocol = imap
> accept = 143
> connect = <mail-fqdn>:143
>
> [mail2-imaps]
> accept = 993
> connect = <mail-fqdn>:143
>
> [mail2-pop3]
> protocol = pop3
> accept = 110
> connect = <mail-fqdn>:110
> [mail2-pop3s]
> accept = 995
> connect = <mail-fqdn>:110
>
> [mail2-smtp]
> protocol = smtp
> accept = 25
> connect = <mail-fqdn>:25
>
> [mail2-smtps]
> accept = 465
> connect = <mail-fqdn>:465
>
> [mail2-smtps-submission]
> debug = 7
> protocol = smtp
> accept = 587
> connect = <mail-fqdn>:587
> ```
>
> In the logfile I have the following entries upon connecting
>
> ```
> 2018.04.30 09:20:50 LOG7[5]: Service [mail2-smtps-submission] started
> 2018.04.30 09:20:50 LOG7[5]: Option TCP_NODELAY set on local socket
> 2018.04.30 09:20:50 LOG5[5]: Service [mail2-smtps-submission] accepted connection from 41.13.8.49:56890
> 2018.04.30 09:20:50 LOG6[5]: s_connect: connecting 10.10.11.2:587
> 2018.04.30 09:20:50 LOG7[5]: s_connect: s_poll_wait 10.10.11.2:587: waiting 10 seconds
> 2018.04.30 09:20:50 LOG5[5]: s_connect: connected 10.10.11.2:587
> 2018.04.30 09:20:50 LOG5[5]: Service [mail2-smtps-submission] connected remote server from 10.10.11.11:42466
> 2018.04.30 09:20:50 LOG7[5]: Option TCP_NODELAY set on remote socket
> 2018.04.30 09:20:50 LOG7[5]: Remote descriptor (FD=23) initialized
> 2018.04.30 09:20:50 LOG7[5]: RFC 2487 detected
> 2018.04.30 09:20:50 LOG7[5]:  <- 220 <mail-fqdn> ESMTP Postfix
> 2018.04.30 09:20:50 LOG7[5]:  -> 220 <mail-fqdn> stunnel for ESMTP Postfix
> 2018.04.30 09:20:51 LOG7[5]:  <- EHLO [100.125.153.220]
> 2018.04.30 09:20:51 LOG7[5]:  -> 250-<mail-fqdn>
> 2018.04.30 09:20:51 LOG7[5]:  -> 250 STARTTLS
> 2018.04.30 09:20:51 LOG7[5]:  <- STARTTLS
> 2018.04.30 09:20:51 LOG7[5]:  -> 220 Go ahead
> 2018.04.30 09:20:51 LOG6[5]: Peer certificate not required
> 2018.04.30 09:20:51 LOG7[5]: TLS state (accept): before/accept initialization
> 2018.04.30 09:20:51 LOG7[5]: SNI: no virtual services defined
> 2018.04.30 09:20:51 LOG7[5]: TLS state (accept): SSLv3 read client hello A
> 2018.04.30 09:20:51 LOG7[5]: TLS state (accept): SSLv3 write server hello A
> 2018.04.30 09:20:51 LOG7[5]: TLS state (accept): SSLv3 write certificate A
> 2018.04.30 09:20:51 LOG7[5]: TLS state (accept): SSLv3 write key exchange A
> 2018.04.30 09:20:51 LOG7[5]: TLS state (accept): SSLv3 write server done A
> 2018.04.30 09:20:51 LOG7[5]: TLS state (accept): SSLv3 flush data
> 2018.04.30 09:20:51 LOG7[5]: TLS state (accept): SSLv3 read client certificate A
> 2018.04.30 09:20:52 LOG7[5]: TLS state (accept): SSLv3 read client key exchange A
> 2018.04.30 09:20:52 LOG7[5]: TLS state (accept): SSLv3 read certificate verify A
> 2018.04.30 09:20:52 LOG7[5]: TLS state (accept): SSLv3 read finished A
> 2018.04.30 09:20:52 LOG7[5]: TLS state (accept): SSLv3 write change cipher spec A
> 2018.04.30 09:20:52 LOG7[5]: TLS state (accept): SSLv3 write finished A
> 2018.04.30 09:20:52 LOG7[5]: TLS state (accept): SSLv3 flush data
> 2018.04.30 09:20:52 LOG7[5]: New session callback
> 2018.04.30 09:20:52 LOG7[5]:      2 server accept(s) requested
> 2018.04.30 09:20:52 LOG7[5]:      2 server accept(s) succeeded
> 2018.04.30 09:20:52 LOG7[5]:      0 server renegotiation(s) requested
> 2018.04.30 09:20:52 LOG7[5]:      0 session reuse(s)
> 2018.04.30 09:20:52 LOG7[5]:      2 internal session cache item(s)
> 2018.04.30 09:20:52 LOG7[5]:      0 internal session cache fill-up(s)
> 2018.04.30 09:20:52 LOG7[5]:      0 internal session cache miss(es)
> 2018.04.30 09:20:52 LOG7[5]:      0 external session cache hit(s)
> 2018.04.30 09:20:52 LOG7[5]:      0 expired session(s) retrieved
> 2018.04.30 09:20:52 LOG6[5]: TLS accepted: new session negotiated
> 2018.04.30 09:20:52 LOG6[5]: No peer certificate received
> 2018.04.30 09:20:52 LOG6[5]: Negotiated TLSv1.2 ciphersuite ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 (128-bit encryption)
> 2018.04.30 09:20:52 LOG7[5]: Compression: null, expansion: null
> 2018.04.30 09:20:52 LOG6[5]: Read socket closed (read hangup)
> 2018.04.30 09:20:52 LOG7[5]: Sending close_notify alert
> 2018.04.30 09:20:52 LOG7[5]: TLS alert (write): warning: close notify
> 2018.04.30 09:20:52 LOG6[5]: SSL_shutdown successfully sent close_notify alert
> 2018.04.30 09:20:52 LOG6[5]: TLS fd: Connection reset by peer (104)
> 2018.04.30 09:20:52 LOG6[5]: TLS socket closed (SSL_read)
> 2018.04.30 09:20:52 LOG7[5]: Sent socket write shutdown
> 2018.04.30 09:20:52 LOG5[5]: Connection closed: 156 byte(s) sent to TLS, 30 byte(s) sent to socket
> 2018.04.30 09:20:52 LOG7[5]: Remote descriptor (FD=23) closed
> 2018.04.30 09:20:52 LOG7[5]: Local descriptor (FD=22) closed
> 2018.04.30 09:20:52 LOG7[5]: Service [mail2-smtps-submission] finished (4 left)
> ```
>
> This is the error I am getting from K9-Mail
>   [K9-Mail Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEcfp.png)
>
> The google mail app just tells me:
>   [Google Mail Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3fKE.png)
>
> Alpine (linux commandline smtp client)
>   [Alpine Client Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytQ6w.png)
>
> Any advise from the gurus?
>
> Kind regards

Comment: Do  `<mail-fqdn>:25` and `<mail-fqdn>:587` successfully support SMTP authentication when you make a direct unencrypted connection to those services with those same mail clients? Or: is stunnel the problem or your mail server. (Also, rather than using stunnel to proxy traffic I would simply  configure mail-fqdn that seems to be running Postfix directly with your certificates...)

Comment: Why do you use stunnel at all? Any currently supported SMTP server software can do TLS natively. Get rid of stunnel and configure the SMTP server.

Comment: Hi @MichaelHampton, I am using stunnel to setup a split horizon. The mail server still needs to be able to handle unencrypted, or reduced security connections from inside the network.

HBruijn I can connect on SSL to the mailserver when the stunnel is out of the loop

Comment: That's why there are separate ports for everything. It still doesn't make sense to use stunnel.

Comment: There is also the issue of the mail server not supporting anything above TLSv1 as well as the some of the end user mail clients not anything above SSLv3. The risk on both of these points will be mitigated by the forced use of a VPN connection for non-secure connections and connections through the stunnel is then used for access from the greater internet for secure mobile access

Comment: *" I can connect on SSL to the mailserver when the stunnel is out of the loop"* - that is all fine and dandy, but as far as I can tell your stunnel configuration terminates the TLS connection and makes a non-SSL connection to your mailserver. Typically mailservers are configured to NOT allow authentication to take place when no SSL/TLS is used.

Comment: @HBruijn, yes I just tested and AUTH is not allowed on an unencrypted connection to the server, thank you for the pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comments:

The problem is that your mail server is already configured with an SSL certificate and will therefore only allow SMTP authentication when it detects a secure encrypted connection.

As far as I can tell Your stunnel server terminates the secure connection a client makes and establishes a second, unencrypted, clear text smtp connection to your mail server.

The mail server then refuses to accept any authentication request made by the client because, as far as it can determine, otherwise the client will send their username and password over an insecure connection.

The problem is that stunnel is designed to convert clear text protocols to SSL secured and vice versa but what you want to do requires a “man in the middle” setup where you take an incoming SSL connection and create an outgoing SSL connection which requires some trickery

https://serverfault.com/a/247967/37681

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to HBruijn for pointing me in the right direction.

I ended up doing the following, extracted from my config:

```
[mail2-smtp]
protocol = smtp
accept = 25
connect = localhost:26

[mail2-smtps]
accept = 465
connect = localhost:26

[mail2-smtp-submission]
protocol = smtp
accept = 587
connect = localhost:26

[mail2-smtp-ssl-client]
protocol = smtp
accept = 26
client = yes
connect = <mail-fqdn>:587
```

The key is the last part that establishes a secure connection to the mail server.